# Magento2: Overwrite custom module template

Tags: magento2

I have two custom modules. Say for example,

```
Module_A
Module_B
```

I have created **module.xml** of Module B with sequence of Module A. Like this,

```
<module name="Module_B" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Module_A"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

I want to overwrite Module_A's template file in Module_B and I am using luma theme.

I have tried to overwrite it in **app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Module_A/templates/(phtml file)**. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

To override a module phtml file I would take one of the two following approaches:

-

**Override template with XML Layout**

Override the phtml file with a xml layout file in Module_B to tell Magento to load the phtml file for the block from Module_B instead of Module_A.
This is very effective way even for major changes in layout blocks but you will have to keep track of the blocks names for any changes in future updates.

*Please follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134898/36376) to know how to change the phtml file for specific block with xml layout override.*

-

**Override template with theme files**

Create a child theme of Luma (or other themes) and start include the phtml file for module Module_A like this:

```
app/design/frontend/customtheme/Module_A/{layout,templates,web}/(phtml file)
```

Personally, I would prefer this approach in case you want to do some quick changes and fixes to Module_A rendered blocks.

You can take [Luma](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma) as a reference for you because it basically does the same.